# Assignment inside for loop returning null

Tags: apex, soql, loop

I am not sure what it is but for some reason my assignment inside a for loop returns null. Below is my code:

```
public class myClass{
    public static void myMethod(list<Project_task__c>incomingPT){
        for(project_task__c projt : incomingPT){
        system.debug('project account is: '+projt.project__r.account__c);
        id testid = [select project__r.account__c from project_task__c where name =:projt.name]                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [0].project__r.account__c;
        system.debug('testId is: '+testid);
        }
     }
}
```

Note: I know it's not best practice to put a SOQL inside a for loop - in this case I put it in there for testing purpose.
`projt.project__r.account__c` returns null instead of an id value but the the testid returns an id as expected.  `Project_task__c` has a look-up to project with api name `project__c`. The `project__c` object in turn has a look-up to the account with api name `account__c`. 
I am calling it from inside an after trigger => myclass.mymethod(trigger.new);
I don't see why this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: What is "incomingPT"? Did you query "projt.project__r.account__c" to populate this list?

Comment: show us the code where you fill in *incomingPT*. I bet problem is there

Answer (score 0):

I think that's an invalid assignment. Try

> id testid = [select project__r.account__c from project_task__c where name =:projt.name **LIMIT 1**]**.project__r.account__c**;

Comment: That is not where the OP is stating his issue is. You are correct though that it will error there so the OP code is incomplete. But this does not answer the question